# Manter aba em jquery javascript ao dar refresh na pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia, tenho a seguinte duvida, tenho um sistema de abas em javascript mas sempre que seleciono uma aba e atualizo a pagina ele volta automaticamente para a primeira o que e ruim pois pretendo colocar botoes que atuam com get, enfim como posso fazer para manter na mesma aba se atualizar ou der um get estando na mesma pagina? segue codigo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content div:nth-child(1)").show();
  $(".abas li:first div").addClass("selected");       
  $(".aba").click(function(){
      $(".aba").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      var indice = $(this).parent().index();
      indice++;
      $("#content div").hide();
      $("#content div:nth-child("+indice+")").show();
   });

 $(".aba").hover(
      function(){$(this).addClass("ativa")},
      function(){$(this).removeClass("ativa")}
  );              
});
```

```
<div class="TabControl">
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="abas">
            <li>
                <div class="aba">
                    <span>Estatisticas</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="aba">
                    <span>Slides</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="aba">
                    <span>Produtos</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="aba">
                    <span>Serviços</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="aba">
                    <span>Usuarios</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="float:right;"><div class="aba"><span>Alterar Senha</span></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="exit">
        <ul>

            <li class="exit"><a href="logoff.php">Sair</a></li>
            <li><input type="text" value="Master" disabled="disabled"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="conteudo">
            Conteúdo da aba 1
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo">
            Conteúdo da aba 2
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo">
            <?php include("produtos.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo">
            Conteúdo da aba 4
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo">
            Conteúdo da aba 5
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo">
            Conteúdo da aba 6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Salve o índice ao qual corresponde a aba em localStorage.**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<style
>body {
  padding: 15px;
}
</style>
<div class="TabControl">
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Estatisticas" data-toggle="tab">Estatisticas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Slides" data-toggle="tab">Slides</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Produtos" data-toggle="tab">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Serviços" data-toggle="tab">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Usuarios" data-toggle="tab">Usuarios</a></li>
            <li style="float:right;"><div class="aba"><span>Alterar Senha</span></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

 <div id="content">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Estatisticas">Conteúdo da aba 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Slides">Conteúdo da aba 2</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Produtos">Conteúdo da aba 3</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Serviços">Conteúdo da aba 4</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Usuarios">Conteúdo da aba 5</div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<script>

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
   localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
// Aqui salva o índice ao qual corresponde a aba. Você pode vê-lo na ferramenta de desenvolvimento do Chrome.

//Obtém os dados da localStorage
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');

// No console, ele mostrará a aba onde você fez o último clique e o 
// salve em "activeTab". Deixo o console para você ver. E quando você der refresh
// no navegador, o último em que você clicou estará ativo.

console.log(activeTab);

if (activeTab) {
   $('a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}

</script>
```

> [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) - nos permite armazenar dados de forma simples e sem expiração, ou seja, ficam lá enquanto não apagarmos por código ou pelo próprio navegador.
>
> [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)- seu funcionamento é idêntico aos do localStorage, com a diferença de que os dados só duram durante a sessão, elas só serão apagadas quando o usuário fechar o navegador.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Eu aconselharia a usar um *local storage* do navegador, pode ser feito em JS com

```
var abaAtual = 1;
// Salvar a aba atual quando trocar
localStorage.setItem('abaAtual ', abaAtual);

// Buscar se tem uma aba atual selecionada
var abaAtual = localStorage.getItem('abaAtual');
console.log('Aba Atual: ', abaAtual);
```

O *local storage* é basicamente uma forma de salvar um par de chave-valor no armazenamento do navegador

Comment: Onde exatamente posso encaixar isso dentro do meu codigo, sou quase completamente leigo em javascript :(

Comment: Na tua função `$(".aba").click(function(){ ... });` que tu usa para exibir a aba clicada, tu salva qual ele clicou com `localStorage.setItem('abaAtual ', indice)` (indice é a tua variável que identifica qual aba está clicada certo?)... e no load da página que tu tens `$(".abas li:first div").addClass("selected");` para deixar a primeira aba como sendo a primeira exibida certo? Aqui tu usa o get `var abaAtual = localStorage.getItem('abaAtual');` e se tiver um valor tu sabe qual aba selecionar, e tiver null tu usa o mesmo código de antes pra exibir a primeira

Comment: nao deu certo :( , acredito ter feito errado, fiz assim  $(".abas li:first div").addClass("selected"); var abaAtual = localStorage.getItem('abaAtual');     
      $(".aba").click(function(){
          $(".aba").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
          var indice = $(this).parent().index();
          indice++;
          $("#content div").hide();
          $("#content div:nth-child("+indice+")").show();
    localStorage.setItem('abaAtual ', indice)
      });

Comment: Quando troca de aba tu está salvando o valor do indice da aba clicada, se logo após `var abaAtual = localStorage.getItem('abaAtual');` tu der um `alert(abaAtual);`tu vai ver que ele deve dar um alerta com o valor correto salvo... Mas tu pega o valor do storage, salva na `var abaAtual` e não faz nada com esse valor, tu precisa montar uma lógica para com esse valor fazer algo, atualmente tu só lê e não faz nada, continua apenas com `$(".abas li:first div").addClass("selected");` então sempre a selecionada será a primeira

Comment: E quando for comentar código usa ele cercado por ` para ficar mais fácil de ler

Comment: obrigado por essa ultima dica, sou novo e tava mesmo querendo saber como faz isso

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Não esquece de marcar a resposta como correta se for o caso, assim tu ajuda outras pessoas que venham a ter a mesma dúvida no futuro

Comment: consegui com a solucao do amigo acima muito obrigado pela ajuda.